# cakephp 2 disabled cache after save

Tags: cakephp-2.0

after insert or delete i don't wish delete view cache, but cake do it automatically.
How disabled clear cache after save, delete functions?

My try, but still the same:

```
if($this->User->save($data, array('callbacks' => false)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add this to your model or AppModel.

```
public function afterSave($created) { 
   Cache::clear();
   parent::afterSave($created); 
}
```

Remove `parent::afterSave($created);` if in the model itself.

If you don't want to empty the cache completely, you can target via `Cache::delete($key)` or by group: `Cache::clearGroup($groupname);`